# How to only keep rows which have more than one value in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, subset

I often try to do the following operation, but there's an immediate solution which is most efficient in pandas:

I have the following example pandas DataFrame, whereby there are two columns, `Name` and `Age`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Barbara',25], ['Bob',72], ['Clarke',13], ['Clarke',13], ['Destiny', 45]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'], dtype=float)

print(df)
      Name   Age
0     Alex  10.0
1      Bob  12.0
2  Barbara  25.0
3      Bob  72.0
4   Clarke  13.0
5   Clarke  13.0
6  Destiny  45.0
```

I would like to remove all rows which do have a matching value in `Name`. In the example `df`, there are two `Bob` values and two `Clarke` values. The intended output would therefore be:

```
      Name   Age
0      Bob  12.0
1      Bob  72.0
2   Clarke  13.0
3   Clarke  13.0
```

whereby I'm assuming that there's a reset index.

One option would be to keep all unique values for `Name` in a list, and then iterate through the dataframe to check for duplicate rows. That would be very inefficient.

Is there a built-in function for this task?

Comment: Check out `pd.duplicated`.

Comment: Please close this question; it is embarrassing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `duplicated`

```
df[df.Name.duplicated(keep=False)]
     Name   Age
1     Bob  12.0
3     Bob  72.0
4  Clarke  13.0
5  Clarke  13.0
```

Comment: Maybe add a `.reset_index(drop=1)` postfix for extra credit?

Answer (score 3):

Use `drop_duplicates`, and only get the ones that are dropped:

```
print(df[~df['Name'].isin(df['Name'].drop_duplicates(False))])
```

Output:

```
     Name   Age
1     Bob  12.0
3     Bob  72.0
4  Clarke  13.0
5  Clarke  13.0
```

If care about the index, do:

```
print(df[~df['Name'].isin(df['Name'].drop_duplicates(False))].reset_index(drop=1))
```

Output:

```
     Name   Age
0     Bob  12.0
1     Bob  72.0
2  Clarke  13.0
3  Clarke  13.0
```

Comment: Good answer , if you interesting the direct way

Comment: A lot of research to answer this question, and I find your answer is exactly the code I get...

Comment: @Samveen Happy that you found this, and that which helps :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward which brings me to the point that it took me 15 minutes of research to answer this question. Makes you wonder about the question, doesn't it ;-).

Comment: @Samveen Hi there, I'm trying to get the moderators to delete this question, as it's too obvious. Please request that it's deleted

Comment: @EB2127 Please don't!!! it's not good to delete questions that have useful answers, so instead of that, please accept mine or W-B's answer.